# Object disintegrates into shadow and pieces when I change viewport?

Tags: 3d-view, error

im a noob trying out blender. All was going well until suddenly when I change the view port it disintegrates? I dont know how to describe it.

I was just changing viewports when that happened, how can I fix it?

To add: I dont have any textures or uv unrapping. Only some modeling, subdivision surface, smoothing and I applied a boolean before subdivision. Thats all

[image]

[image]

Comment: you must have pressed Alt B (Clipping Border), press Alt B again

Comment: @moonboots oh wow you're right. I was panicking for a moment, thanks a lot :)